# Make OpenGL code accesible through QtScript

Tags: c++, qt, opengl

I'm making in Qt an application for educational purposes.. The goal is that students can write any OpenGL code that they want, and see what the results are in a QGLWidget inherited class..

For that I'm trying to use QtScript in this way:
The OpenGL code students write should be executed in a reimplemented painGL() method...

But the problem is that from the script I would generate from their OpenGL code, I can't access OpenGL methods, or enums, or enything, as they are neither Q_INVOKABLE methods nor slots...

Any ideas about how can I do that??

Here is the code:

*.h:

```
#include <QtOpenGL/QGLWidget>
#include <GL/glu.h>
#include <QColor>

#include <QtScript>


class Graficador : public QGLWidget
{

    Q_OBJECT

public:
    Graficador(QWidget *parent = 0);

    void dibujar(QString);

    void ejecutar_script();

protected:
    void initializeGL();
    void resizeGL(int w, int h);
    void paintGL();

private:
    void draw();

    QScriptEngine motor;
    QScriptValue valor;

    QString orden_motor;
};
```

*.cpp:

```
    Graficador::Graficador(QWidget *parent)
    : QGLWidget(parent)
{
    setFormat(QGLFormat(QGL::DoubleBuffer | QGL::DepthBuffer));
}

void Graficador::initializeGL()
{
    qglClearColor(Qt::black);
}

void Graficador::resizeGL(int w, int h)
{
    glViewport(0, 0, w, h);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glOrtho(-w / 2.0, w / 2.0, -h / 2.0, h / 2.0, -1.0, 1.0);

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
}

void Graficador::paintGL()
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    draw();
}

void Graficador::draw()
{
    QScriptValue resultado;
    resultado = motor.evaluate(orden_motor); //Here is where the script should be executed
}


void Graficador::dibujar(QString orden)
{
    orden_motor = orden; //Here I load the script content, which is generated from what the students write
}

void Graficador::ejecutar_script()
{
    valor = motor.newQObject(this);
    motor.globalObject().setProperty("app",valor);
}
```

The QString "orden_motor" is the code, which I receive from a QPlainTextEdit, that is a child of the same QMainWindow that Graficador is.. When the student presses a QPushButton, "dibujar" and "ejecutar_script" are executed, as well as "updateGL", which are all members of the Graficador class...
So the script should be executed... But instead, when I read the results of QScriptValue "resultado", I get that none of the functions I don't declare as Q_INVOKED are recognized... And that includes all OpenGL methods, as well as OpenGL enums...

If anybody could throw me some light here, I would really appreciate it!!

The ideal case for me would be that the entire QGLWidget class could be accessible from the script... I know it's not the ideal thing to do, but I think it's the most suitable way to do this...

But again, any ideas are welcome!

Thanks!!

Comment: Cannot you write a wrapper class?

Comment: "students can write any OpenGL code that they want"  Are you trying to execute *arbitrary* OpenGL code in QScriptEngine!?

Comment: @cmannett85 yes, that would be the ideal case... It doesn't necessarily need to be done with QScriptEngine, I also tried exporting the code to a *.cpp and compiling it into a brand new application...
But I was trying to find a more elegant solution, and so I chose this approach... 
But like I said, I'm open to suggestions!

I know it's too much to ask from QScriptEngine, but at the moment it's all I can come out with...

Comment: @LaszloPapp I don't really see how a wrapper class would be of use here... Can you please explain yourself? Thanks for the answer!